# JQuery to prevent an element from getting focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How to prevent an input element (text, text area, select, radio button, checkbox) from getting focus?
I basically want to make them disabled without changing disabled or readonly attribute but denying them focus.
Is there a neat way to scan the DOM using certain search criteria and apply that to the search result?
Say I want to find all input that are not tagged with a certain css class and make them un-selectable!

Comment: Unless you take care to do this exactly right, this would result in all sorts of navigation by keyboard issues, and poor accessibility - but, using jqueery for such things for a personal use page that nobody will ever see is fine, Iguess ... Personally, I'd make disabled inputs `disabled`, and then use CSS to style them as I want them - and the best part is - no "jqueery" required

Comment: making them disabled won't work as we want all elements to be submitted. These are massive pages. Making them readonly won't work with radio buttons and dropdown selections.

Comment: That's what the readonly attribute is for. What doesn't work exactly with radio-buttons and dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements that should be allowed focus the `focus` class. Then use a `focus` event handler that unfocuses the element.

```js
$(document).on("focus", ":input:not(.focus)", function() {
  $(this).blur();
  console.log("Focus blocked");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"> No focus<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="focus"> Focus
```

This uses event delegation so you can add and remove the `focus` class dynamically.

Comment: Can that class selection be negated? Like select all elements that don't have that class?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this works only on text boxes, it has no effect on radio buttons or select dropdowns and check boxes.

Comment: I've added an executable snippet, and it seems to work. After you click on the second checkbox, you can uncheck it using the space key because it has focus. But when you click on the first box it doesn't get focus, so you can't change it with the space key.

Comment: If you click on a checkbox it will check/uncheck it even if it doesn't get focus.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got what you mean but can you please run this:

```js
$('#disabler').change(function() {

  resetFields();
  
  var this_value = $(this).val();
  
  if(this_value != 'none'){
    $('.'+this_value).attr('disabled', true);
  }
  
  
});

$('.disabler').click(function(){

  resetFields();
  
  var this_value = $(this).attr('id');
  
  $('.'+this_value).attr('disabled', true);

});

$('#reset').click(function(){

  resetFields();

});

function resetFields()
{
  $('.first, .second').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="first" value="A"><br/>
<select class="first"><option value="1">A</option></select><br/>
<textarea class="first" col="2" row="10">A</textarea><br/>

<br/><br/>

<input class="second" value="B"><br/>
<select class="second"><option value="1">B</option></select><br/>
<textarea class="second" col="2" row="10">B</textarea><br/>

<br/><br/>

<select id="disabler">
  <option value="none">-select-</option>
  <option value="first">Disable first</option>
  <option value="second">Disable second</option>
</select><br/>

<button id="first" class="disabler">Disable first only</button><br/>
<button id="second" class="disabler">Disable second only</button><br/>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```